# Do I have to chmod 777 my NFS folder when I share?

Tags: redhat, nfs

Under Redhat, if I export a folder as an NFS mount, does the folder have to have RW for users/groups/others? Right now /storage/software is -rwxr-xr-x root/root

i.e. /etc/exportfs

```
/storage/software *(rw,sync)
```

On my client, I can mount but I can't write. I'm using a regular user and NOT root.
I think "no_root_squash" fixes it but I really don't want that. Then again, nor do I want to have to chmod 777 the folder on the server.

Answer (score 3):

NFS uses the filesystem permissions across systems.

A reasonable solution would to use a group that all users were members of and set the SGID bit on the directory as well.  Public writable is for /tmp.  If you must, at least set the sticky bit.

Comment: then it looks like I'll have to chmod 777 the folder then. It's just a folder for the developers to store all their files.

Comment: The guy just provided you the solution NOT to do chmod 777. You have to use a group that has writable access on your shared folder. Just create a group on all servers make sure it has the same ID and then SGID it: `find /foldername/ -type d -print0|xargs -0 chmod g+rwxs;chmod -R u+rw,g+rw,o-w /foldername/;chgrp -R newgroup /foldername/`

Answer (score 2):

You should have the same user IDs and group IDs on both servers. At least those that will use the NFS folder.

Comment: Not gonna happen. My users can mount from their workstations or from servers.

Comment: @luckytaxi: This is why planning network security is so important. I highly recommend conisdering retooling your network before the company grows more, and the problems become much worse. I do understand what this is asking; but it's pain now, or more later.

Comment: For NFS to work well on a network, you need some form of centralised UID management (LDAP, NIS, rsyncd /etc/passwd), and ideally very controlled access to root accounts.